# Font Awesome & Unicode & Variable in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, icons, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I want to show fontAwesome icons in my app.

I can show with string type icons like this:

`<Text style={{fontFamily: 'fontAwesome'}}>&#xf0e8;</Text>`
print icon. Working well.

But I need to show icons with variable like this:

```
let icon2 = "&#xf0e8;";
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'fontAwesome'}}>{icon}</Text>
```

then print to screen `&#xf0e8;` not icon.

I share with you expo snack link. You can try this easily.

https://snack.expo.io/@wyrustaaruz/Zm9udG

Comment: can you try `icon="\u&#xf0e8;"`

Comment: error I am sorry not working.
```Parsing error: Bad character escape sequence```

Comment: See also https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fontawesome which seems rather easier to read than unicode characters

Comment: @dvdsmpsn thank you but more library low performance :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of

```
let icon2 = "&#xf0e8;";
```

you need to define it as;

```
let icon2 = "\uf0e8";
```

In javascript, you need to define unicode characters with `"\u"` when you assign it to a variable. So it can recognize and parse unicode characters properly.

**Edited for your question in your comment;**

Your icons are hexadecimal. So we can delete first 3 character from icon. After that, we parse that unicode value as integer and we can convert to 
 a unicode string by `String.fromCharCode`.

```
icon2 = icon2.substr(3);
icon2 = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(icon2, 16));
```

Comment: I need to replace text with this code. ```icon2 = icon2.replace("&#x","\u");
icon2 = icon2.replace(";","");``` but getting error ```Parsing error: Bad character escape sequence``` because of   "\u"

Comment: i answered you question in edited answer. Good luck.

Comment: for some who has a unicode like this "0xe926", you can delete 2 characters and it will work perfect like.
    icon2 = icon2.substr(2);
    icon2 = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(icon2, 16));